# CasperJS evaluate() is not executing from within each() block

Tags: javascript, web-crawler, phantomjs, casperjs

So I'm crawling a page, collecting links, then I would like to crawl those links to complete my dataset. Here's some code:

crawl.js:

```
var casper = require("casper").create({
    waitTimeout: 3000,
    pageSettings: {
        userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:23.0) Gecko/20130404 Firefox/23.0"
    },
    clientScripts: ["includes/jquery.min.js"],
    verbose: true
});

var followers = require('./followers');
var currentPage = 1;
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;

Object.size = function(obj) {
    var size = 0, key;
    for (key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++
    }
    return size;
};

var collectFollowers = function() {
    var url;
    this.echo("capturing page " + currentPage);
    this.capture("wowhead-p" + currentPage + ".png");

    // don't go too far down the rabbit hole
    if (currentPage >= 5 || !this.exists(x('//*[text()="Next ›"]'))) {
        processFollowers.call(casper);
        return terminate.call(casper);
    }

    currentPage++;
    this.echo("requesting next page: " + currentPage);
    url = this.getCurrentUrl();

    var links = this.evaluate(function() {
        var obj = {}
        $('.listview-cleartext').map(function(){ 
            obj[$(this).text()] = $(this).attr('href');
        });
        return obj;
    });

    for (key in links) {
        followers.followers[key] = links[key];
    }

    this.echo("Page links: " + Object.size(followers.followers));
    //this.emit('update.followers', links);
    this.thenClick(x('//*[text()="Next ›"]')).then(function() {
        this.waitFor(function() {
            return url !== this.getCurrentUrl();
        }, collectFollowers, processFollowers);
    });
};

var processFollowers = function() {
    this.echo("Total followers:" + Object.size(followers.followers));
    this.each(Object.keys(followers.followers), function(casper, key) {
        this.thenOpen('http://wowhead.com' + followers.followers[key]).then(function() {
            this.echo("On http://wowhead.com" + followers.followers[key]);
            this.evaluate(function() {
                this.echo("Inside the evaluate statement.");
                if ($('a[href=#quests]').length) {
                    this.echo("Has quest!");
                    $('a[href=#quests]').click();
                    var questURL = $('#tab-quests').show().find('.listview-cleartext').attr('href');
                    var questName = $('#tab-quests').show().find('.listview-cleartext').text();
                    this.echo("Quest URL: " + questURL);
                    followers.followers[key] = {"name": key, "quest": {"url": questURL, "name": questName}};
                } else {
                    this.echo("Does not have quest!");
                }    
            });
        });
    });
}

var terminate = function() {
    this.echo("Done.").exit();
}

casper.start("http://wowhead.com/followers=2");
casper.waitForSelector(x('//*[text()="Next ›"]'), collectFollowers, processFollowers);
casper.run();
```

followers.js:

```
var require = patchRequire(require);
var utils = require('utils');
var followers = {};
exports.followers = followers;
```

followers is used to store a global variable, an object that I continually build and update as I crawl pages. So I go through 3 pages of data, collect links successfully, then begin to process them. As it stands, CasperJS appears to open each page successfully, however the evaluate function is never called.

I was able to get this functionality to work within PhantomJS with some async logic, but switched to casper because it appeared as though this would be taken care of under the hood. I've tried various combinations of thenOpen(), then() and open(), thenOpen() without the then(), etc..  What am I messing up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`casper.evalute()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate) is the sandboxed page context in the same way the as the PhantomJS version ([`page.evaluate()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html)). It has no access to variables defined outside.

`this` inside of `evaluate()` refers to `window` and not `casper` and I doubt that there is such a function like `window.echo()`. If you want to receive console messages from the page context, you need to register to the `remote.message` event:

```
casper.on("remote.message", function(msg){
    this.echo("remote: " + msg);
});
```

You have to explicitly pass the result out of the page context and add it there:

```
var result = this.evaluate(function() {
    console.log("Inside the evaluate statement.");
    if ($('a[href=#quests]').length) {
        console.log("Has quest!");
        $('a[href=#quests]').click();
        var questURL = $('#tab-quests').show().find('.listview-cleartext').attr('href');
        var questName = $('#tab-quests').show().find('.listview-cleartext').text();
        console.log("Quest URL: " + questURL);
        return {"url": questURL, "name": questName}};
    } else {
        console.log("Does not have quest!");
        return null;
    }
});
if (result) {
    followers.followers[key] = {name: key, quest: result};
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Artjom. This is very similar to an old revision of my code.. I had a suspicion that I wasn't using the namespaces correctly. Problem solved!